# Grouping numerical values pivot using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a price check of the products we sell each week, and each entry represent the price change from last week to this week, so values can be positive or negative.

I am using vba codes to create a pivot table, which will show ranges/groups of prices. Below is the section of my codes that I have currently but not producing the desired results since I can't know what my lowest and highest change in price. For the grouping method, everything up to $999 (from negative number) I would like to group them by $100 and anything above $1000 I would like make it as one group and display it as $1,000 +.

So I need help with custom grouping of numerical values and have pivot to display the ranges like $100-$199 and $1,000 + . First picture is based on my codes and second graph is what I hope to get, I know the total is not the same for both so just get my grouping method.

I am not sure if I can use `Case` statement or `If` statements to assign them into ranges. And if I can, how can I modify my codes so I can do this custom grouping.

```
        'Group by
        Dim pf As PivotField

        Pvt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
        Set pf = Pvt.PivotFields("$ Premium Difference from Prior Term")
        pf.LabelRange.Group Start:=-300, End:=5000, By:=100
        pf.Caption = "Price Range"


        'Filter out blanks in row labels
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
Dim LR88, i As Long

    LR88 = PSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LR88 - 1
        PSheet.Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]="""",""Hide"","""")"
        Next i

Dim rng, mycell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A:A" & LR88 - 1)
        For Each mycell In rng.Cells
            If mycell = "Hide" Then
                    pi.Visible = False
            Else
            pi.Visible = True

            End If

         Next mycell
         Next pi
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't use something like frequency?

Comment: i m fairly new to vba can always try as long as you can help me get started....

Comment: Frequency is a function, so no need for VBA really. You define the buckets/ranges (called bins) and Excel does the heavy lifting. Have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FREQUENCY-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9

Comment: i can check it out, thank you, and i just need to display the results as pivot table and i was doing vba codes since i started with vba on the first half where I did the data manipulation and all the look ups....thats why I figured I should continue using vba codes...

Comment: Makes sense, if you have to use a pivot table, I would always define the ranges in the underlying data and then have the pivot display it. But I've never been a pivot expert...

Comment: Thank you again, I have 4 pivot tables I need to manually group by so that is why I was looking for ways to cut down editing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what the Start and End arguments do. You don't need to know in advance what your smallest and largest numbers are...because the Start and End parameters are the thresholds at which data *outside* those bounds are grouped together. In other words, if you wanted groupings of 100, and wanted to lump together anything below -1000 together and also lump anything over 1000 together, you would use this:

```
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Price Difference")
pf.LabelRange.Group Start:=-999, End:=1000, By:=100
pf.Caption = "Price Range"
```

...which would give you these groupings, based on some random data I generated:

[image]

If you wanted to automatically change the formatting of this so that it *appears* as currency values, then you need some code that also intelligently adds the $ signs in all the relevant places, like this:

```
    Sub AmendGroupings()
Dim pt          As PivotTable
Dim pf          As PivotField
Dim pi          As PivotItem
Dim sCaption    As String

Const sDelim = "to" 'Change this if you want to use something other than the English word "to".

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") '<= Change as appropriate
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Price Range") '<= Change as appropriate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

pf.LabelRange.Group Start:=-1000, End:=1000, By:=100

'Format so that groupings appear as currency values
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    sCaption = "$" & pi.Caption
    sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "$-", "|")
    sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "-", " to $")
    sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "to $ to $", "to -$")
    sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "|", "-$")
    sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "$< to ", "<-")
    If InStr(sCaption, ">") Then sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, ">", "") & " +"
    'sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "to", sDelim) '<= Uncomment if you want to use a different delimiter
    sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "$1000", "$1,000")
    pi.Caption = sCaption
Next pi

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

...which does this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input but I think there is a slight difference in the answer since the way we group is differently. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks,

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how you want to group differently? I'm not quite understanding what it is you want.

Comment: To clarify, is there a lower bound (-x) at which you want to group numbers below that lower bound together? I understand than numbers above positive 1000 are to be grouped together. What about numbers say below negative 1000?

Comment: For negative entries, I would hope to get ranges like -$199 - $100, -$99 to -$0 as results so have $99 as ranges, and anything above 0 has been displayed in the picture above. For the lowest bound, I haven't seen anything that is less than -$1,000. If that is solved, I m still looking for ways to label it correctly since it's in dollar amount. I hope this helps clarifying some of the questions you have but let me know.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect your requirements. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi just some minor things not sure if you can take a look at it. 1) Formatting like $1,000 instead of $1000 2) for the last entry, we have >$1,000 but I am looking for $1,000 + 3) Right now I am seeing <-$1000 but really there are no entries and anyway to hide it? I did if statements but no luck. 1) & 2) were shown in my results from yesterday so.

Comment: I've done amendments 1 and 2 and updated my answer. I don't understand what you mean by 3, so you'll have to post a screenshot.

Comment: Hello thanks, I got your revision and please see the picture for desired results. I think before if my entry is blank, I just filter out blanks but now it can be any of the pivot item so I want to know if we can filter out if Total Values are 0.

Comment: I added my version of filtering but it's showing $1,000+ and 5 as Total Values and the rest is filtered out...not sure why...

Comment: Thanks, I started another question just for this part so if you have figured out, please go and answer. Thanks again

Comment: Cool...posted an answer at that one two.